# Don't save a message in "sent mail" if sent via Gmail

Tags: php, symfony

With Symfony2 it is very easy to configure Gmail as smtp provider. A great extra feature is that the sent messages are stored in the "sent mail" folder.

But for certain emails it is not desirable to store them, like "forgot password" emails. I can't find any trace in the documentation about not storing a message in the "sent mail" folder.

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/email/gmail.html

Comment: It's not up to you...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a GMail specific behavior, because swiftmailer (the mailer bundle in symfony) uses only SMTP to send emails and SMTP is for sending mails and not for storing them.

The task to store a sent email in the sent folder (locally or in the IMAP folder) is the job of the MUA (Mail User Agent, your email client) and not of the server. But yeah, Google do their own things.

Comment: Sounds very clear and logic. Does the SwiftMailer store a sort-of key after the message is sent, by which I can locate the message programatically on the Gmail servers?